# Why is my code printing "The queue is empy" after displaying the queue once

Tags: c, pointers, struct, while-loop, queue

I had forgotten to add a temporary node in the beginning in the display() method but later I added it, still, I am facing the same issue. I was unable to find the problem in my code.

I have added the complete code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Queue
{
    struct Node *front, *rear;
};

struct Node* newNode(int k)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->key = k;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct Queue* createQueue()
{
    struct Queue* q = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    q->front = q->rear = NULL;
    return q;
}

void enQueue(struct Queue* q, int k)
{
    struct Node* temp = newNode(k); 
    if (q->rear == NULL)
    {
        q->front = q->rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    q->rear->next = temp;
    q->rear = temp;
}
void deQueue(struct Queue* q)
{
    if (q->front == NULL)
    {
        printf("The Queue is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    struct Node* temp = q->front;
    printf("Deleted Element: %d\n",q->front->key);
    q->front = q->front->next;
    if (q->front == NULL)
        q->rear = NULL;
    free(temp);
}
void display(struct Queue* q)  
{  
    struct Queue* temp=q;
    if(temp->front == NULL)  
    {  
        printf("The Queue is Empty.\n");  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        printf("Queue contains the following elements:\n");  
        while(temp->front != NULL)
        {  
            printf("%d\t",temp->front -> key);  
            temp->front = temp->front -> next;  
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
}  

int main()
{
    struct Queue* q = createQueue();
    int choice=0;     
    while(choice != 4)  
    {  
        printf("Choose from the following by entering the index number:\n1.Insert an element\n2.Delete an element\n3.Display the elements in queue\n4.Exit\n");  
        scanf("%d",&choice);  
        switch(choice)  
        {  
            case 1:  
            {   
                int k;
                printf("Enter the element you want to insert: ");
                scanf("%d",&k);  
                enQueue(q,k);
                break;  
            }  
            case 2:  
            {  
                deQueue(q); 
                break;  
            }  
            case 3:  
            {  
                display(q);  
                break;  
            }  
            case 4:   
            {  
                printf("\nThe program has ended."); 
                exit(0); 
                break;   
            }  
            default:  
            {  
                printf("\nInvalid Input! Please try again.");  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters an allocation of memory for a new mode can fail. In this case your code will invoke undefined behavior. Rewrite the function `newNode` the following way

```
struct Node * newNode( int k )
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->key = k;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Correspondingly the function `enQueue` should be rewritten the following way

```
int enQueue( struct Queue *q, int k )
{
    struct Node *temp = newNode( k );
    int success = temp != NULL;
 
    if ( success )
    {
        if ( q->front == NULL)
        {
            q->front = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear->next = temp;
        }

        q->rear = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function `deQueue` should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to issue a message.
You could write one more function that reports whether the queue is empty. For example

```
int isEmpty( const struct Queue *q )
{
    return q->front == NULL;
}
```

The function `deQueue` can be defined the following way

```
void deQueue( struct Queue *q )
{
    if ( !isEmpty( q )
    {
        struct Node *temp = q->front;

        q->front = q->front->next;
        if ( q->front == NULL ) q->rear = NULL;

        free( temp );
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
case 2:
{
    if ( isEmpty( q ) )
    {
        printf("The Queue is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Deleted Element: %d\n",q->front->key);
        deQueue( q );
    }
}
```

Within the function `display` after this assignment

```
struct Queue* temp=q;
```

the pointer `temp` points to the same object of the type struct Queue as the pointer q. That is you are accessing the same object using two different pointers. So using the pointer `temp` you are changing the original object of the type struct Queue

```
temp->front = temp->front -> next;
```

So after this loop

```
while(temp->front != NULL)
```

the pointer `front` of the original object of the type struct Queue will be equal to NULL.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void display( const struct Queue *q )  
{  
    printf("Queue contains the following elements:\n");  

    for ( const struct Node *current = q->front; current != NULL; current = current->next;)
    {  
        printf( "%d\t", current->key);  
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
case 3:
{
    if ( isEmpty( q ) )
    {
        printf( "The Queue is Empty.\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        display( q );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me! I should have seen that I am using the original front node

Answer (score 1):

In your `display` function, what do you think this line of code does?

```
temp->front = temp->front -> next;
```

It's moving the front of your queue forwards until it ends up pointing to `NULL`. Because you're not making another copy of the queue by assigning `q` to `temp` - they both point to the same queue.

Instead, what you want to do is make `temp` a `struct Node` and move that along the queue - something like this

```
void display(struct Queue* q)  
{  
    struct Node* temp=q->front;
    if(temp == NULL)  
    {  
        printf("The Queue is Empty.\n");  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        printf("Queue contains the following elements:\n");  
        while(temp != NULL)
        {  
            printf("%d\t",temp -> key);  
            temp = temp -> next;  
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
}
```